# trying to execute base62 operation in unix with more than 25 digits in a row, but awk treating a default value

Tags: awk, gawk

Below is my  code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; flag=0;}
{
x=$2
rem=int(x)%62
quo=int(x/62)
flag=0
while(quo>62)
{
sub_rem=int(quo)%62
quo=int(quo/62)
if(flag==0)
{
grp_rem=sub_rem
}
else
{
grp_rem=sub_rem","grp_rem
}
flag++
}
printf "%d|%d|%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,quo,grp_rem,rem >> "text.out"
}
end{}
' test.txt
```

Issue with the above code is:

1) when trying to pass input with more than 18 or more taking a default value

```
Sample data: 
1|123456789123456789123456789
2|24536789215457896314563
```

2) After doing base62 operation for certain rows, output is different for others.

```
sample data: 
row1:  1|276
row2:  1|276
row3:  1|277
row4:  1|278
.
.
.
.
row 300: 300|276


samplet out: 
row1:  1|276|4,0,28
row1:  1|276|4,0,28
row1:  1|277|4,0,27
row1:  1|278|4,0,28
...
row 300: 300|276|4,1,28
```

Is there anyway to resolve the above issues?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not obvious what you want to do, what output you expect and what you get instead. If you want people to help make a small test case that clearly shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting the `awk` integer precision.

Given your input file:

```
$ cat file
1|123456789123456789123456789
2|24536789215457896314563
```

A simple `print` is not showing the right result:

```
$ awk -F\| '{print $2+0}' file
123456789123456791337762816
24536789215457895776256
```

A way forward is to use option `--bignum` or `-M`:

```
$ awk --bignum -F\| '{print $2+0}' file
123456789123456789123456789
24536789215457896314563
```

Note that the option `--bignum` is available from GNU awk version 4.1.0.

Comment: Thanks @oliv but how to use --bignum in awk
can you help me with this

Comment: @siva10442 Just add the option `--bignum` to your `awk` command line and run your program again. If you have another problem, please be more specific.

Comment: I see the awk version 3.1.7 only, is there any other way I can use this program  with current version (3.1.7)

Comment: @siva10442 I don't see any easy way. If you can't update the awk to a recent version, then you'd better go for another programming language (perl, python, etc...)